# Having some problems using Rails 3, keeps going to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm relatively new to Ruby, and Rails, I need to use Rails version 3.2.19, for some tutorials I'm following along, I get all kinds of errors trying to follow along with Rails 4...anyways, when I do: gem install rails --version=3.2.19, it shows that it installed it. When I do rails -v, it shows Rails 4.1.5....I thought maybe if I create a new Rails app, specifying version 3.2.19, that would work. Surprise, it showed up as Rails 4.1.5 in my Gemfile...what gives? I tried manually changing it in the Gemfile and running bundle install, but then everything breaks when I fire up the Rails server...I searched those errors on here, and no surprise, all the answers were about how those are errors when trying to use Rails 3, in an app that was generated with Rails 4.

I'm really stumped about this folks and would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)please install rvm if YES,check the rvm ls 
and set ruby 1.9.3 as default.and then make new project 
2)can you see the which version of ruby using if 2+ then it will be rails 4
if you want to use rails 3 then use 1.9.3 ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing `rails _3.2.19_ new myapp` 
when you're generating your app?

Also when you change rails version on your Gemfile, you have to run `bundle update rails` to update the version.

Comment: I did install it that way, as rails _3.2.19_ new MyPortfolio, I did not know about bundle update rails, so I did that now, and then when I run rake db:create or rake db:migrate I get this error: rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "MyPortfolio" does not exist
/Users/adamcarter/Code/MyPortfolio/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment

Comment: Which one of my suggestion did you follow?

Comment: That's another issue though, search on stack for a solution